# How can i solve this ascii error in python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

```
def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    with open('%s_facebook_statuses.csv' % page_id, 'wb') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file)
        w.writerow(["status_id", "status_message", "link_name", "status_type", "status_link",
           "status_published", "num_likes", "num_comments", "num_shares"])

        has_next_page = True
        num_processed = 0   # keep a count on how many we've processed
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

        print "Scraping %s Facebook Page: %s\n" % (page_id, scrape_starttime)

        statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, 100)

        while has_next_page:
            for status in statuses['data']:
                w.writerow(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status))

                # output progress occasionally to make sure code is not stalling
                num_processed += 1
                if num_processed % 1000 == 0:
                    print "%s Statuses Processed: %s" % (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now())

            # if there is no next page, we're done.
            if 'paging' in statuses.keys():
                statuses = json.loads(request_until_succeed(statuses['paging']['next']))
            else:
                has_next_page = False


        print "\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)
scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
```

---

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 40-43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm writing code to scrape through Facebook pages to gather all the posts in cvs file.
The code is working properly when there is only the English language, but 
the error above appears when I try to scrape through pages that post in Arabic.
I know the solution is to use utf-8 but I don't know how to implement it on the code.

Comment: could you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried using the `encode` function of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is not in this code, I suspect is in your processFacebookPageFeedStatus function. But when you are formatting your fields you'll want to make sure any that may contain unicode characters are all decoded (or encoded as appropriate) in utf-8.

```
import codecs

field_a = "some unicode text in here"
field_a.decode('utf-8')  -----> \u1234\u........
field_a.encode('utf-8')  -----> Back to original unicode
```

Your CSV probably doesn't support unicode, so you need to decode each field in your source data.

Debugging unicode is a pain, but there are a lot of SO posts about different problems related to encoding/decoding unicode

Comment: I solved it by adding 
import sys
reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

and I used pandas to read it and every thing is fine for now

Answer (score 0):

import sys

reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

I added this piece of code and it works fine when I open this file in pandas .

there are no other errors or what so ever for now

Comment: You might read this article about that fix, I found it informative:  https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Comment: I think i should have read your comment earlier, I'm getting troubles now when i try to work with any text, any idea how to revert it or solve its problems !!

Comment: You should probably do a search for similar problems and if you can't find a good equivalent issue, try posting a new question. Be sure to include examples of your errors. If you are having a lot of issues it's probably too complex to try addressing in comments like this